# Tensorflow InvalidArgumentError: TypeError: unhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray'

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, conv-neural-network

Trying to build a simple machine learning model using Tensorflow in Colaboratory, but I keep hitting the same error at the `model.fit` stage:

```
InvalidArgumentError: TypeError: unhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray'
```

I've tried modifying the batch size and number of steps in `model.fit`, but to no avail.

I thought perhaps it was linked to the very small sample size I'm working with (just to establish a working through-put), but I can't see how.

Reproducible code:

```
import os
os.environ["TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL"]="2"
import tensorflow as tf
import math
import tensorflow_hub as hub
import numpy
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras import layers
from sklearn.metrics import roc_curve
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator

from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/drive/', force_remount=True)

train_examples = 60
test_examples = 60
validation_examples = 60
img_height = img_width = 224
batch_size = 2

model = keras.Sequential([
      hub.KerasLayer("https://tfhub.dev/google/imagenet/nasnet_mobile/feature_vector/4",
                     trainable=True),
      layers.Dense(1, activation="sigmoid"),
])

train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
      rescale = 1.0/255,
      rotation_range = 15,
      zoom_range = (0.95, 0.95),
      horizontal_flip = True,
      vertical_flip = True,
      data_format = "channels_last",
      dtype = tf.float32
)

validation_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale = 1.0/255, dtype = tf.float32)
test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale = 1.0/255, dtype = tf.float32)

train_gen = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    "/content/drive/My Drive/data/train",
    target_size=(img_height, img_width),
    batch_size=batch_size,
    color_mode="rgb",
    class_mode="binary",
    shuffle=True,
    seed=123
)

validation_gen = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    "/content/drive/My Drive/data/validation",
    target_size=(img_height, img_width),
    batch_size=batch_size,
    color_mode="rgb",
    class_mode="binary",
    shuffle=True,
    seed=123
)

test_gen = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    "/content/drive/My Drive/data/test",
    target_size=(img_height, img_width),
    batch_size=batch_size,
    color_mode="rgb",
    class_mode="binary",
    shuffle=True,
    seed=123
)

from tensorflow.keras import optimizers
optimizers.RMSprop()

model.compile(
      optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=3e-4),
      loss=[keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy(from_logits=False)],
      metrics=["accuracy"],
)

model.fit(
    train_gen,
    epochs=1,
    steps_per_epoch=train_examples//batch_size,
    validation_data=validation_gen,
    validation_steps=validation_examples//batch_size,
)
```

Gives me this block of error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
InvalidArgumentError                      Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-49-1b2c74b84635> in <module>()
      5     steps_per_epoch=train_examples//batch_size,
      6     validation_data=validation_gen,
----> 7     validation_steps=validation_examples//batch_size,
      8 )

1 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py in raise_from_not_ok_status(e, name)
   7105 def raise_from_not_ok_status(e, name):
   7106   e.message += (" name: " + name if name is not None else "")
-> 7107   raise core._status_to_exception(e) from None  # pylint: disable=protected-access
   7108 
   7109 

InvalidArgumentError: TypeError: unhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray'
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/script_ops.py", line 273, in __call__
    return func(device, token, args)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/script_ops.py", line 151, in __call__
    outputs = self._call(device, args)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/script_ops.py", line 158, in _call
    ret = self._func(*args)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/autograph/impl/api.py", line 649, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/data/ops/dataset_ops.py", line 4482, in py_function_wrapper
    ret = self._func(*nested_args)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/data/ops/dataset_ops.py", line 1043, in generator_next_fn
    flattened_types)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/util/traceback_utils.py", line 153, in error_handler
    raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/data/ops/dataset_ops.py", line 810, in get_iterator
    return self._iterators[iterator_id]

TypeError: unhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray'


     [[{{node EagerPyFunc}}]] [Op:IteratorGetNext]
```

Comment: Do you have a typo in your validation generator? Should it not be `validation_gen = validation_datagen.flow_from_directory(*)`?

Comment: @AloneTogether Yes! I've tried that and it's working now. Stupid mistake, thanks so much.